# How can I test a function expecting objects of some concrete types if I don't want to create objects of those types?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, mocking, c++17

Given a pre-existing base class `B`, I had to implement a derived class like this

```cpp
struct D : public B {
    bool pred(X const& x, Y const& y) const override;
};
```

where the `X` class is a complicated monster, and `Y` is just a wrapper to a range `X`s, i.e. `Y` supports meaningful `begin()` and `end()`.

Next I had to write some tests for this class, but going through creating some `X`s and `Y`s to test `pred` against seemed to be very complicated, so I reasoned that all that `pred` needs to do with `y` is looping on its wrapped range of `X`s, and all it needs to do on all of those `X`s and on the input `x` is just calling `.someMember()` on them.

Then why not testing `pred` on some classes that pretend to be `X` and `Y`?

So I rushed and defined appropriate `Xmock` and `Ymock` classes in the testing TU, and then moved `pred` implementation into a template free function:

```cpp
template<typename X, typename RangeX>
bool helper(X const& x, RangeX const& r) {
    // implementation
}
```

and rewrote the member function in terms of the one above:

```cpp
bool D::pred(X const& x, Y const& y) const {
    return helper(x, y);
}
```

Except that soon I found that I had to move `helper`'s definition to the header file otherwise the testing TU wouldn't see it.

---

This is to say that when the idea above came to my mind it looked promising: I make the function that I want to test a template, so that I can pass to it whatever I want, provided it satisfies some concept. But than I was stuck into language-specific difficulties.

---

So the question is, is the one I described above a valid strategy? Or, can it be made valid by using other methods to deal with templates (explicit instantiation...)? Or maybe I should simply give up to the idea that I have to create object of those concrete types `X` and `Y` to test `pred`?

Comment: *"Then why not testing pred on some classes that pretend to be X and Y?"* - This basically means decoupling function from X and Y by introducing interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know of any perfect solution to this problem in C++. If the `class X` was already a polymorphic type and the `X` interfaces you use in your `bool pred` were overridable, then of course you could create a `class MockX: public X` and test your code against it. But I guess you cannot change that part of the library code.

Given that, your solution with templated helper

```
template<typename X, typename RangeX>
bool helper(X const& x, RangeX const& r) {
    // implementation
}
```

is the only workaround to implicitly test `bool pred` without creating real `X` instance. Unfortunately you need to pollute your header with this template definition.

If `class X` definition was in another library than `class B` definition (and from your question I guess it is not the case), you could also use testing trick from C language: link your test executable against mock implementation of that library (and include headers from mocked lib includes dir).